# MongoDB :: Why Embedded Documents Indices Don't return documents in reverse order?

Tags: mongodb, database

This is from [MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes):

```
db.factories.insert( { name: "xyz", metro: { city: "New York", state: "NY" } } );
db.factories.ensureIndex( { metro : 1 } );
// this query can use the above index:
db.factories.find( { metro: { city: "New York", state: "NY" } } );
//As well as this
db.factories.find( { metro: { $gte : { city: "New York" } } } );

// But this query will not return the document because the order of the fields is significant and doesn't match in this case
db.factories.find( { metro: { state: "NY" , city: "New York" } } );
```

Why is the order of the documents significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in JSON and BSON the order of fields makes difference when serialized. I.e.

```
{ city: "New York", state: "NY" }
```

is not the same as

```
{ state: "NY" , city: "New York" }
```

The value actually indexed will be "New YorkNY" in the first case and "NYNew York" in the second case (roughly). Since there's no scheme no way to normalize field order prior searching the embedded document in the index.

To overcome this you can use compound index:

```
db.factories.ensureIndex( { "metro.city": 1, "metro.state": 1 })
```

And query with (here the order doesn't matter):

```
db.factories.find( { "metro.city": "New York", "metro.state": "NY" } )
```

Comment: source for "Because in JSON and BSON the order of fields makes difference"?

Comment: @Radagaisus this was a badly formed statement. I meant it makes difference in this context (serializing and indexing). BSON or JSON itself doesn't enforce any order and object comparison semantic is up to implementation.

Comment: "Since there's no scheme no way to normalize field order prior searching the embedded document in the index"... just an idea: how about sorting fields by alphabetical order (of field name)?

Comment: @yi_H this is also a solution. In general one will need to maintain same field order when inserting and querying. Note when updating with `$set` field order can be altered by MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah, strange feature of MongoDB.. never quite understood it. In one hand it remembers document field order on the other hand when you try to do atomic updates the whole feature breaks. I wonder are there actually any people out there who use this feature.